# Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS keeps killing my Ethernet connection when it cannot find an Internet connection

Tags: networking, ethernet, wired, static-ip, tcp-ip

I have a device (a nuclear radiation detector, specifically) that streams binary data over a TCP/IP connection. To stream the data, I simply connect it to my laptop via Ethernet and set the wired connection with a static IPv4 address via the Wired Settings menu. However, whenever I try and connect it, it connects for a short while, while Ubuntu looks for an Internet connection, and then as soon as Ubuntu cannot find an Internet connection I get an error message that says "Connection Failed. Activation of network connection failed." and Ubuntu kills the connection. In the time while Ubuntu searches for an Internet connection I am able to stream data, but as soon as it's killed I lose the stream.

I have not been able to find any questions on the forum that addresses this issue.

Essentially my question is: how can I tell Ubuntu to keep the wired connection open even if there isn't an Internet connection?

Comment: Do you have DNS AUTO set to OFF? Edit your question with a screenshot of your IPv4 panel from your Wired Settings. Report back to @heynnema

Comment: I actually solved the problem by just setting the static IP address through the terminal using the ifconfig command. Probably should have just done that from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by just setting the static IP address using the ifconfig command as opposed to doing it through the GUI settings. Much easier.